# Metatrader5 prevent autotrade

Tags: metatrader5

I would like to prevent MetaTrader5 to be generating autotrades on my Demo Account at "MetaQuotes", i.e. for hedging reasons, I'd like to have multiple Buy and Sell Positions open. My problem is that sell positions are being closed when I open buy positions and vice versa. Is that a limitation of the demo account or do I have anything else wrong?

The Setting "Extras --> Options --> Expert Advisors" is switched to off.

Thanks in advance, Michael

Answer (score 0):

Due to https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/211, hedging is not possible in MT5. MT5 architecture differs from MT4 architecture in that point.